role_required decorator for FastAPI route
Disclaimer: It's been quite a long time since I asked questions here, and also I am a complete novice in FastAPI.
I am playing with FastAPI authorization and wondering how can I protect my routes from users who are authenticated but do not have permission for that specific routes.
I have some code that solves this.
Here is my route:
@router.get('/student_route_only')
@role_required(allowed_roles=[UserRole(name='student')])
async def student_route_only(
    token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)],
    auth_service: AuthService = Depends(get_auth_service),
    user_data: UserAuthResponse = None,
):
    return UserAuthResponse(
        user_id=user_data.user_id,
        role=user_data.role,
        name=user_data.name,
    )


@router.get('/routes_for_student_and_admin')
@role_required(allowed_roles=[UserRole(name='student'), UserRole(name='admin')])
async def routes_for_student_and_admin(
    token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)],
    auth_service: AuthService = Depends(get_auth_service),
    user_data: UserAuthResponse = None,
):
    return UserAuthResponse(
        user_id=user_data.user_id,
        role=user_data.role,
        name=user_data.name,
    )

This is my pydantic model:
class UserAuthResponse(BaseModel):
    user_id: int
    role: str
    name: str

class UserRole(BaseModel):
    name: str

    @validator('name')
    def name_must_be_valid(cls, value):
        allowed_roles = ['admin', 'student', 'teacher']
        if value.lower() not in allowed_roles:
            raise ValueError(
                f"Invalid role. Allowed roles are: {', '.join(allowed_roles)}"
            )
        return value

and this are my decorator that does the job:
def role_required(allowed_roles: list[UserRole]):
    def decorator(func):
        @wraps(func)
        async def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            auth_service = kwargs.get('auth_service')
            token = kwargs.get('token')
            user_data = await auth_service.get_current_user(token)
            if not user_data or user_data.role not in [role.name for role in allowed_roles]:
                raise HTTPException(
                    status_code=status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN,
                    detail='This operation is forbidden for you',
                )
            kwargs['user_data'] = user_data  # pushing gotten user_data back
            return await func(*args, **kwargs)

        return wrapper

    return decorator

I have searched for the relatively simple decision for role route protecting in FastAPI but did not find something that are not hard to implement.
Is it okay to use such kind of code in production?
Because I think it is quite simple to use, for instance if I have to protect some route and make it available let's say only for admin I can simply do this:
@router.get('/admin_route_only')
@role_required(allowed_roles=[UserRole(name='admin')])  # and that's it. The decorator does the rest of the job
async def admin_route_only(
    token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)],
    auth_service: AuthService = Depends(get_auth_service),
    user_data: UserAuthResponse = None,
):
    return UserAuthResponse(
        user_id=user_data.user_id,
        role=user_data.role,
        name=user_data.name,
    )

On the other hand my PyCharm does not like that auth_service and token in function are not used (but they are needed in the decorator). Would it be okay for other developers? And for linters?
And also is it okay to delegate authorization to decorator like this and then push the user data back through kwargs?

You're hit by FastAPI magic. If they didn't parse a view function signature up to type annotations, you could have added token and user_data in decorator (without black magic - I feel like a hacky solution still exists), without requiring them in the function. That's the drawback of seemingly convenient signature-based dispatch.

Please include Review Context with code submissions,
such as the imports needed at the top.
convenience constant
@role_required(allowed_roles=[UserRole(name='student')])

nit: It would be nice to define an object so we can write allowed_roles=[Student]
Similarly for Admin.
(Or perhaps name them StudentRole & AdminRole.)
    token: Annotated[str, Depends(oauth2_scheme)],

In a similar way, this occurs often enough
that writing token: Token would be more convenient.
{optional, mandatory} params
async def student_route_only(
    token: ... ,
    auth_service: AuthService = Depends(get_auth_service),
    user_data: UserAuthResponse = None,
):

The second argument is never referenced and can be elided.
The third argument is marked optional with default of None,
yet we always dereference its .user_id, .role, and .name attributes.
Attempting that on a None object will raise an AttributeError exception.
Putting a default value in the signature seems ill advised.

my PyCharm does not like that auth_service and token in function are not used (but they are needed in the decorator).

Oh, now I see the tension.
I agree the @role_required decorator has a lot going for it.
But maybe a decorator isn't the best fit here.
Instead of customarily starting each method with a decorator,
you might customarily call verify_role( ... )
as first statement in the method.
Each method signature tells a story to several audiences:
developer, IDE, linters such as mypy.
As written, I feel this signature is not being entirely forthright,
it isn't quite giving an accurate depiction of the inputs being consumed at each level.
permissive check
    def name_must_be_valid(cls, value):
        ...
        if value.lower() not in allowed_roles:

This seems more permissive than necessary.
No need to downcase.
Just check for set membership, and if caller offered "aDmIn" then they
get what they deserve and will soon repair their bug.
Also, mentioning "Allowed roles" is a thoughtful touch.
But what a maintenance engineer reading a bug report will really
want to know is what value was passed in, so consider adding that
to the diagnostic message.
None
def role_required( ... ):
            ...
            auth_service = kwargs.get('auth_service')
            token = kwargs.get('token')

The .get() with default of None suggests these are optional args.
But then we immediately make an unconditional dereference of the first,
passing in the second.
Maybe auth_service.get_current_user(None) could make sense in some circumstances.
But here the role_required identifier suggests that we can only
make forward progress when we know the role of an authenticated user.
Might as well just plunge ahead with e.g.
auth_service = kwargs['auth_service'], and
if we raise a KeyError, fine, that's what happens.
Likely it would be easier to reason about the various cases
if this helper used try and relied on an except clause
to deliver any 403's to the web client.

            user_data = await auth_service.get_current_user(token)
            ...
            kwargs['user_data'] = user_data  # pushing gotten user_data back


is it okay to delegate authorization to decorator like this and then push the user data back through kwargs?

Yes, absolutely.
If we're going the decorator approach,
then side-effecting kwargs to transmit user data
down to the called function makes perfect sense.
